# How do I send POST data using TW3HttpRequest

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

So I've started playing with SMS and I've tried to make a program (label and button) to hit a website with a post request and display the result.

I have no problems with Hints/Warnings/Errors and everything looks good to me. The following code is a rework of a couple of existing examples mashed together.

```
procedure TForm1.ExecuteCmd;
var
  whttp : TW3HttpRequest;
  wParams : string;
begin
  wHttp := TW3HttpRequest.Create;
  try

    whttp.OnDataReady := lambda (Sender)
      if (w3Label1.caption = '') then
        w3Label1.caption := wHttp.ResponseText;
    end;

    whttp.OnReadyStateChange := lambda (Sender)
      if (wHttp.ReadyState = 4) and (wHttp.Status = 200) then
      begin
        if (w3Label1.caption = '') then
          w3Label1.caption := wHttp.ResponseText;
      end;
    end;

    wParams := 'cmd=TestID1';
    whttp.open('POST','http://www.server1.com/executecmd.php');
    whttp.RequestHeaders['Content-type'] := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    whttp.Send(wParams);
  finally
    wHttp.free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.W3Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ExecuteCmd;
end;
```

The problem is this, when I actually click the button I get the following error message:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of null [line #6277]

The error is in the auto generated code and seems to have no relation to what I've written specifically.  If I take out all references to ReadyState from my code I still get the error.

What am I missing? I feel like it has something to do with the Lambda functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are expecting `whttp.Send` to block. `Send`, as its JavaScript equivalent, is asynchronous. Before the `POST` could even execute, `whttp` object is freed (in the `finally` block). When callback (`OnReadyStateChanged`) is called, `whttp` was already freed (and is now null) and you are then trying to call `ReadyState` on that freed (null) object.

Another reason for confusion is that `object.Free` in Delphi for Windows/OS X destroys the object while in Smart it merely sets the `object` reference to `nil` and leaves the destruction to JavaScript's garbage collection. That's why the `whttp` is still alive after the `Free` and why the `OnReadyStateChanged` is called at all.

This works fine:

```
uses 
  W3System, W3Graphics, W3Components, W3Forms, W3Fonts, W3Borders, W3Application,
  W3Button, W3Inet, W3Memo;

type
  TForm1=class(TW3form)
    procedure W3Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    {$I 'Form1:intf'}
    whttp: TW3HttpRequest;
  protected
    procedure InitializeForm; override;
    procedure InitializeObject; override;
    procedure Resize; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TForm1}

procedure TForm1.W3Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  wParams: string;
begin
  whttp := TW3HttpRequest.Create;

  whttp.OnReadyStateChange := lambda (Sender)
    if (whttp.ReadyState = 4) and (wHttp.Status = 200) then
    begin
      W3Memo1.Text := wHttp.ResponseText;
      whttp.OnReadyStateChange := nil;
      whttp := nil;
    end;
  end;

  wParams := 'cmd=TestID1';
  whttp.open('POST','http://httpbin.org/post');
  whttp.RequestHeaders['Content-type'] := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  whttp.Send(wParams);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks gabr that is exactly what the issue was.  By taking out the `whttp.free;` it solved the issue.  Once you explained it, JavaScript is a garbage collected language, it makes total sense. I guess I'm going to have to change my way of thinking about these types of things if I'm going to try and make use of SMS.